# Hosting Multiple websites on nginx similar to apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, nginx

I am trying to host multiple websites in nginx similar to apache. In apache we have folder called htdocs. We put directories and files inside htdocs and if the URL is something like

```
www.example.com
```

then we can access the directories and files inside the htdocs folder as

`www.example.com/exampledir1` and `www.example.com/exampledir2`

I want to do the same with nginx. Is it possible. I have a server in my company which has a static IP. Ive installed nginx on it and by default i have hosted one rails app on it with the following lines in the `nginx.conf` file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mycomp.does-it.net;
  root /var/www/mysamplerails/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env development;
}
```

This site is accessible to me if i go to the url "mycomp.does-it.net"

now what i would like to do is have another rails app and access it from `mycomp.does-it.net/mysecondrailsapp` as the root.

Ive googled a lot and im ending up no where. I'm from apache background and these are some of my first tries in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Use **passenger_base_uri** option. See documentation: [Deploying to a sub URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri)